# Why hibernate session.clear() does not cancel pending session.save()?

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I have the following code:

```
Color color = new Color(null,"B12",null,1);

Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);

session.beginTransaction();
session.save(color);
session.clear();

session.getTransaction().commit();

session.close();

sessionFactory.close();
```

Documentation says about method [`Session#clear`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#clear()) the following:

> Evict all loaded instances and cancel all pending saves, updates and deletions.

Why doesn't it cancel `save()` and still stores data to database?  Please help me with it!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?   If you want a encapsulated action that can be cancelled, try using a transaction.    While this appears to be a bug, I can't think of why it'd be done the way you've got it in production.

Comment: i'm trying to learn things related to persistence context how this all works and don't understand why it does not work like it's supposed to.

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8118572/5078385) useful?

Comment: What you have there is odd from a workflow perspective.  Typically you'd rollback the transaction instead of committing it and not use clear at all.   In my experience, the only time I end up using clear is to clear and flush during large numbers of insert/updates.

As to why it still persists inside the transaction commit, it might be a bug, but its a corner case.

Comment: I know that just curious about documentation.